# Using dateInput on a CRUD Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am looking for some assistance regarding using a dateInput in a CRUD app. I used the source code from the iPub blog post about CRUD Shiny Apps : https://ipub.com/shiny-crud-app/

I've been trying to modify the code so that there is a dateInput. I was able to get the format to be a date (different source code than below) but it will only show the current date even when you change the input. The solve on that code does not work on the sample code below and this will also demo that the date will not change.

I'm getting only characters instead of a date format and it is the same characters/dates regardless of what is selected via the input.

https://gist.github.com/john-magrini/c9a6a5cf11653b40edc77cffbe632f8b

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm guessing there is something happening around [Line 117](https://gist.github.com/john-magrini/c9a6a5cf11653b40edc77cffbe632f8b#file-r-L117) in your script which reads all the inputs at once. Maybe there is something forcing a cast to a character. I recommend running your Shiny app with breakpoints or running the same code from the console (not as part of Shiny app) to more closely watch the object types.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It looks like the reason it was always the Sys.Date() was because of Sys.Date being in # Cast from Inputs to a one-row data.frame
CastData <- function(data) {
  datar <- data.frame(name = data["name"], 
                      used_shiny = as.logical(data["used_shiny"]), 
                      date_started = data["date_started"],
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  rownames(datar) <- data["id"]
  return (datar)
} Instead of data["date_started"] BUT now it isn't in a date format and when I try as.Date I get the not unambiguous error

Comment: if I do date_started = Sys.Date() I do get a date format but it is always the current date....

Comment: Workaround that is 'ok' for now is just making the date inputs text inputs, specifying the format and using as.character(Sys.Date()) for the defaults; guess I'll have to deal with fat fingers another way for now